# Rewrite Oracle Procedure and trigger for SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration, database-trigger

I have an Oracle procedure to add a row to the JOB_HISTORY table and a trigger   to call the procedure when data is updated on two columns`( job_id, department_id)` in the `table EMPLOYEES`:  I´m trying to rewrite them for Sql server 2008, can anyone help me to rewrite both of them  please? I might have done it with the procedure but cannot do it with the trigger. any suggestion is welcome?

Procedure:

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_job_history
     ( p_emp_id job_history.employee_id%type
    , p_start_date job_history.start_date%type
    , p_end_date job_history.end_date%type
    , p_job_id job_history.job_id%type
    , p_department_id job_history.department_id%type )
     IS BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO job_history (employee_id, start_date, end_date,job_id,department_id)
    VALUES(p_emp_id,p_start_date,p_end_date,p_job_id,p_department_id);
    END add_job_history;
```

Trigger:

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_job_history 
     AFTER UPDATE OF job_id,department_id ON employees
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     add_job_history(:old.employee_id, :old.hire_date, sysdate,
     :old.job_id,:old.department_id);
     END;
```

This is how I wrote the procedure I´m not sure is doing the same thing as the one above though.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE add_job_history
   (@p_emp_id         INTEGER,
    @p_start_date  DATE,
    @p_end_date   DATE,
    @p_job_id      VARCHAR(10),
    @p_department_id        INTEGER  ) AS
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO job_history (employee_id, start_date, end_date, 
    job_id, department_id)
    VALUES(@p_emp_id, @p_start_date, @p_end_date,  @p_job_id,@p_department_id)
   END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TRIGGER update_job_history ON (table_EMPLOYEES)
 AFTER UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN

 if exists(select 1 From inserted as i inner join deleted as d on d.employee_id = i.employee_id where d.job_id != i.job_id or d.department_id != i.department_id)

 begin

insert into job_history (employee_id, start_date, end_date,job_id,department_id)
select  d.employee_id, d.start_date,d.end_date,d.job_id,d.department_id
    from deleted as d


 end

 END;
```

Comment: some Names may not be the same as yours, but the logic is as it is.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Putting two "begin" and two "end" gives me problems I guess. I get the error : The multi-part identifier "d.employee_id" and all of the other fields could not be bound.When I delete one of the "end" at the end of the query gives me one error but only at the row of the last "end"

Comment: that is not the source of issue, let me take a look into this again

Comment: I updated the join condition to `on d.employee_id = i.employee_id`, did you check every column/table name I wrote in the script? it may vary

Comment: @Fab check again, there exists a syntax error before. I updated my answer

Comment: I just wanted to say that in the employee table I don´t have any start_date and end_date . I do have only hire_date

Comment: then where do those two fields exist?

Comment: Hi Long. I think the solution should be similar to this but number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns. :  create trigger update_job_history on tblTriggerTest
after update
as
begin
   set nocount on;
   insert into job_history (employee_id, start_date, end_date ,job_id, department_id)
   select 1 From inserted as i inner join deleted as d on d.employee_id = i.employee_id where d.job_id != i.job_id or d.department_id != i.department_id 
end

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help @Long
I found The answer even if I still have to test the logic of it and i might change  some inserted  i. with d.

```
     create trigger update_job_history on employees
     after update
     as
     begin
     set nocount on;
     insert into job_history (employee_id, start_date, end_date  ,job_id,department_id)
     select i.employee_id,  i.hire_date as start_date , d.hire_date as  end_date, d.job_id ,d.department_id  
     From inserted as i inner join deleted as d on d.employee_id = i.employee_id where d.job_id != i.job_id or d.department_id != i.department_id
     end
```